# Select Records Only Having Records within Supplied Date Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a parent-child table scenario where the child table contains a datetime column, I was to select only those parent records with child records ONLY within the supplied date range.

e.g. Cart - Cart Details where Cart Details has a "DateAdded" column, I want to select all Cart records that ONLY have "Date Added" this week.

Something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cart
JOIN CartDetail ON CartDetail.CartId = Cart.Id
???
```

I'm not sure how to select the cart records where the CartDetail.DateAdded is ONLY within a supplied date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cart AS c
INNER JOIN CartDetail AS cd ON cd.CartId = c.Id
WHERE cd.DateAdded BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
      AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM CartDetail AS cd2
                  WHERE cd2.CartId = c.Id AND
                        cd2.DateAdded < @start_date OR cd2.DateAdded > @end_date)
```

Comment: I believe that this would also select ones that would have records that were added in previous date ranges as well as long as there was at least one record within the given range.

I am looking for ones that ONLY have child records within the given range.

Comment: @Flea I had just realized my mistake. Corrected!

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos Betsos